# Accessing a data.table via column numbers and grep

Tags: r, data.table

If I use this simple data.table (one column)

```
mydata <- data.table(A=c("ID123", "ID22", "AAA", NA))
```

I can find the position of the rows starting by "ID"

```
grep("^ID", mydata[,A])
```

How can I get the same result using numbers instead? (saying I want the first column).

I've tried

```
grep("^ID", mydata[,1, with=F])
```

but it doesn't work.

And more important, I would like to do it in the data.table way, introducing the command inside the brackets.

```
mydata[,grep("^ID",.SD), .SDcols=1]
```

But this doesn't work.

I've found this way, but it's too convoluted

```
mydata[,lapply(.SD, grep,pattern="ID"), .SDcols=1]
```

What's the proper way to do it?

A little bit more complex:
What if I want to count simultaneously how many rows are not NA and start by "ID"?

Something like

```
any(!(grepl("^ID", mydata[,A] ) | is.na(mydata[,A])))
```

but more compact and inside the brackets.

I don't like the fact that grep considers the NA as a not matching instead of outputing an NA too.

Comment: I've found this way, but it's too convoluted mydata[,lapply(.SD, grep,pattern="ID"), .SDcols=1]

Comment: The first answer in the FAQ explains why it "is generally bad practice to refer to columns by number rather than name" https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#j-num One way to count rows is `mydata[ A %like% "^ID" | is.na(A), .N ]` -- `%like%` is just a convenient shortcut to `grepl`. By the way, your example might be better if it included an NA.

Comment: I changed the question title so it would more accurately summarize the request.

Comment: I know using column numbers could be dangerous because they may change on time. But sometimes you need to use them to refer to many columns at once or because that numbers come from a previous filtering.

Comment: I've just found that grepl produces a FALSE whenever you the argument is NA.  Then we don't need to add the is.na() checking. It'd depend on what we want.

Comment: Frank, should you post your reply as an answer I'll choose it.

Answer (score 11):

Don't forget that `data.table` is a `list`, too. So if you *really* and *just* want an entire column as a vector then it is encouraged just to use base R methods on it: `[[` and `$`.

```
mydata <- data.table(A=c("ID123", "ID22", "AAA"))
mydata
#       A
#1: ID123
#2:  ID22
#3:   AAA
grep("^ID", mydata[[1]])   # using a column number
#[1] 1 2
grep("^ID", mydata$A)
#[1] 1 2
```

If you need this in a loop then `[[` and `$` are faster as they avoid the overhead of argument checking inside `DT[...]`. If it's just one call then that overhead is negligible.

`grep("^ID", mydata[,1, with=F])` "doesn't work" (please include the error message that you saw instead of "does't work"!) because `grep` wants a vector but `DT[]` always returns a data.table, even if 1-column, for important type consistency e.g. when chaining. `mydata[[1]]` directly is cleaner, but another way just to illustrate is `grep("^ID", mydata[,1,with=F][[1]])`.

As Frank said in comments, using column numbers is highly discouraged because of the potential for bugs as your data changes over the months and years into the future as the documentation explains.  Use column names instead, within `DT[...]`.

But if you really must, and sometimes it's valid, then how about :

```
..theCol = DT[[theNumber]]
DT[ grep(,..theCol) & ..theCol | ..theCol etc , ... ]
```

The `..` prefix in your variable name kind of means "one up" like a directory path. But any variable name that for sure isn't a column name would do.  This way you can use it several times inside `DT[...]` without having to repeat both the table name `DT` and the column number just to access the column by number several times. (We try to avoid symbol name repetition as much as possible to reduce the potential for bugs due to typos.)

Comment: I know using column numbers could be dangerous because they may change on time. But sometimes you need to use them to refer to many columns at once or because that numbers come from a previous filtering.
My question is a simple example, but I'm working with a big table with 1700 variables.

Comment: Please, Could you explain a little bit more the meaning of ..  ?

Comment: I've tried  ..theCol = DT[[1]]
DT[, grep("^ID",..theCol) | !is.na(..theCol)]
but the result is logical(0)

Comment: @skan `grep` returns a vector indices, possibly of length zero. You want `grepl`.

Comment: @skan: Do read the upcoming change in `[.data.table` referenced in Matt's comments to my earlier but less knowledgeable answer. It will now be possible to use unquoted named column spans with the `":"` operator.

Comment: @42- +1 Btw, unquoted named column spans are already possible when you include `with=FALSE`. The change is that you won't need `with=FALSE`.

Answer (score 2):

One data.table way of indexing a column by number would be to convert to a column name , convert to an R symbol, and evaluate:

```
mydata[ , eval( as.symbol( names(mydata)[1] ) )]
[1] "ID123" "ID22"  "AAA" 

> grep("^ID", mydata[,eval(as.symbol(names(mydata)[1]))])
[1] 1 2
```

But this is not really an approved path to success because of the DT FAQ #1 as well as the fact that row numbers are not considered as valid targets. The philosophy (as I understand it) is that row numbers are accidental and you should be storing your records with unique identifiers.

Comment: How about `mydata[[1]]` ?

Comment: Hah. From the Master. But before I saw the author of this comment I was prepared to say that "[[" was a list-based method and not a true-data.table method. But I could well be wrong about this. I did check: `?'[[.data.table'
No documentation for ‘[[.data.table’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??[[.data.table’
`

Comment: There's no special method for `[[` or `$` on `data.table` so there's no mechanism or need to document.  Nothing different and that's intended: it's just a `list`.  Please feel free to use `[[` and `$` in these situations.  I do.  There is an example and comment in `example(data.table)`:  "`DT[["v"]]   # same as DT[, v] but much faster`"

Comment: I've gotten my hand slapped so many times for using data.frame methods with data.tables that I try to avoid it.

Comment: Not for `[[` and `$` though I hope!

Comment: Have made a change in this area for the next release which is why I jumped in on this one.  Please check out item 3 at the top in [news](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md) and see what you think.

Comment: And to be clear I'm only encouraging `[[` and `$` for reading a single column as a vector.  Assigning using `[[<-` and `$<-` are completely different and we prefer `:=` for that.

Comment: The change#3 is welcome to my reading. I agree completely that the old behavior of returning single literal values from the j argument was of no real value and generally not what would be expected by a new DT-user. And for me, you were being quite clear that it was only being used for extract and not for assignment.